# aggregation according to different conditions on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table @tbl like below, i need to write a query like if there are more than 3 records availble
for particular cid then avg(val of particular cid ) for particular cid should be dispalyed against each id and if there are less than 
3 records availble for particular cid then avg(val of all records availble).

Please suggest.

```
declare @tbl table(id int, cid int, val float )

insert into @tbl 
values(1,100,20),(2,100,30),(3,100,25),(4,100,31),(5,100,50),
(6,200,30),(7,200,30),(8,300,90)
```

Comment: Please provide what you already tried.

Comment: Your description of the problem is not clear. What do you expect as output from the sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Your description is not clear, but I believe you need windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cid) AS cnt
  FROM @tbl
)
SELECT id, (SELECT AVG(val) FROM cte) AS Av
FROM cte
WHERE cnt <=3
UNION ALL
SELECT id, AVG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY cid) AS Av
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 3
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4d6ac6d1e58f9fdc55610065c372859)**

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cid) <= 3 THEN AVG(val) OVER() 
         ELSE AVG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY cid)
    END
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d84ea51844a7d1747da162b43db9e8a9)**

Comment: @Andrew Please check once again plus you have live demo

Comment: missing comma now in place - not sure on the 1 row output per input row, but OP is not clear.

Comment: @lad2025: for cases less than 3 count the values are incorrect because code is considering only ids where count is less than 3 but i need avg of whole table the filter condition <=3 make restriction.Please check and suggest.This code is giving 50 as avg but correct answer is 38.25 in this case.

Comment: @hieko Please provide desired resultset. Row by row as it should be.

Comment: for cid 100  cases values are fine but for all rest cases avg of all val should be taken.I hope that helps.

Comment: @hieko Please check now

Comment: Works perfectly.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @hieko Works perfect but does not have a check mark?

Comment: @paparazzo I didn't get what do you mean by check mark here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following. First calculate the average for each `Cid` depending in it's number of occurences, then join each `Cid` with the `Id` to display all table.

```
;WITH CidAverages AS
(
    SELECT
        T.cid,
        Average = CASE
            WHEN COUNT(1) >= 3 THEN AVG(T.val)
            ELSE (SELECT AVG(Val) FROM @tbl) END
    FROM
        @tbl AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.cid
)
SELECT
    T.*,
    C.Average
FROM
    @tbl AS T
    INNER JOIN CidAverages AS C ON T.cid = C.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarifications in comments, I am thinking this is the intention

```
declare @tbl table(id int, cid int, val float )

insert into @tbl 
values(1,100,20),(2,100,30),(3,100,25),(4,100,31),(5,100,50),
(6,200,30),(7,200,30),(8,300,90);
select distinct
    cid
    , case
    when count(*) over (partition by cid) > 3 then avg(val) over (partition by cid)
    else avg (val) over (partition by 1)
    end as avg
from @tbl;
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdf4c4457220ec64132de7452a034976

```
cid avg
100 31.2 
200 38.25 
300 38.25
```

There are a number of aspects of a query like this that when run at scale though are going to be pretty bad on the query plan, I'd want to test this at a larger scale and tune before using.

The description was not clear on what happened if it was exactly 3, it mentions 'more than 3' and 'less than 3' - within this code the 'more than' was used to determine which category it was in, and less than interpreted to mean 'less than or equal to 3'